# slideDown not working after div content changes more than once

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup, dynamic-content

I cannot figure out why my slideDown only works the first time. I have an element which when clicked adds content to an empty div, then slides the div open. Within that dynamic div content is an element which when clicked slides the div closed, then empties the div content.

This works fine the first go round, but after the "close" element has been clicked, the "open" element will no longer slide down the div. It still replaces the content, but the slide down doesn't work the second time.

In my actual project, the content is generated via an ajax request, but I was able to duplicate the issue in a Fiddle with basic hardcoded dynamic content.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mp72cjm1/1/

```
$('body').on('click', 'span.open', function(){
    var content = '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test';
    content += '<br><span class="close">Close</span>';
    var container = $('div#content');
    $(container).html($(content)).slideDown(1000);
});
$('body').on('click', 'span.close', function(){
    var container = $('div#content');
    $(container).slideUp(1000).queue(function(){ $(this).html(''); });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `.queue()` there. Instead use `.slideUp()`'s callback:

```
var container = $('div#content');
$('body').on('click', 'span.open', function () {
    var content = '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test';
    content += '<br><span class="close">Close</span>';
    $(container).html($(content)).slideDown(1000);
});
$('body').on('click', 'span.close', function () {
    $(container).slideUp(1000, function () {
        $(this).html('');
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mp72cjm1/2/)**